# Issue with canvas (full screen) threejs

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, renderer

The problem that I have on my project is that I've got a **WebViewerGL**, I've added a menu on right side, and I want to add a "Drag and drop" function.

But I've faced with an important problem. When I try to drag an image of my menu to my scene the camera moves and it doesn't let me drag objects.

My question is : **Which is the way to set the canvas adjustable to my menu items?**

I think there is the problem but I don't know the way to solve it.

```
 window.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
     antialias: true,
     alpha: true
 });

 renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
 renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
 document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

Camera code

```
   // init scene and camera
 window.scene = new THREE.Scene();
 var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 1000);
 camera.position.x = 70;
 camera.position.y = 70;
 camera.position.z = 70;
 var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera)

 var gizmo = new THREE.TransformControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
 scene.add(gizmo);
 onRenderFcts.push(function() {

     gizmo.update();
 })


 loadFiles(filesToLoad);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please attach some of the code snippets you have tried yet, to help out the experts to analyse your problem.

Comment: You need to show your camera-related code and your CSS in your post. A link to a simple live example would help. If you don't have sufficient reputation to add a link, then add the link in the comments.

Comment: I wanted to add an image to explain my problem decently but I don't have enough reputation to do that... Image link :i.stack.imgur.com/FkeLM.png (The red line is where I want to set the maximum range of camera and green line is where I want to do my "drag and drop")